# Twitter intent link not working on page, but it does work from dev tools

Tags: javascript, twitter, hyperlink

When I click on the link on the page, I receive the following error:
[twitter.com is blocked twitter.com refused to connect ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4mBf.png)

I use the following code to add the link to the page:

```
  function getQuote() {
    let newQuote = randomQuote().q;
    let newAuthor = randomQuote().a;
  
    let tweetURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&text=';
    tweetURL = tweetURL + encodeURIComponent(newQuote + ' ' + newAuthor);
  
    $('#text').text(newQuote);
    $('#author').text(newAuthor);
    $('#tweet-quote').attr('href', tweetURL);
  
  }
```

If I open up the developer tools in chrome, I can click on the link in the tag and it works perfectly fine.

Why won't it work on the page?

Comment: I have tried building the entire tweetURL and encoding that as well, but it produced the same results.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with my React code. I also had target attribute set to "_blank".
Read the below post, changed it to "_top" and the tweet button started working on my chrome browser.

https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/freeCodeCamp/issues/40089